# Delays or latency in the construction of controllers for every request in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, redis, .net-6.0

We use microservice architecture with .net core 6 for one service that gets configs from other api instead of `appsettings.json` file.
The problem is the existing `latency` for every request or handling event from rabbitmq.
We also saw these logs:

```
11 Feb 2023 17:41:50.406
 Executed controller factory for controller Basket.API.Controllers.MonitoringController (Basket.API)
11 Feb 2023 17:41:49.305
 Executing controller factory for controller Basket.API.Controllers.MonitoringController (Basket.API)
```

that there was more than a second delay in creating a controller.
This is where there is a possibility of latency (my repository class constructor):

```
public RedisBasketRepository(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
           IOptions<BasketSettings> settings,
           IConnectionMultiplexer redis,
           IOptionsSnapshot<Dictionary<string, BrandsConfigurations>> brandsConfigurations,
           IInternalAPICallerService internalAPICallerService,
           IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RedisBasketRepository>();
            _redis = redis;
            _database = redis.GetDatabase();
            _settings = settings?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));
            _brandsConfigurations = brandsConfigurations.Value;
            _internalAPICallerService = internalAPICallerService;
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }
```

There were no errors in the logs.
Because we had also used Redis and there was a possibility of thread theft in the library used to connect to it,
also used the following config to set the minimum number of threads, but the problem still remained:
`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);`

We searched and tried a lot to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IOptionsSnapshot<Dictionary<string, BrandsConfigurations>> brandsConfigurations,
```

Because using the above item results in the following:

> Options are computed once per request when accessed and cached for the
> lifetime of the request.

If there are many configs that you receive through the api when starting the app, and in multiple constructors used by `IOptionsSnapshot`, there will be a lot of delay due to the computing for each item.

If you use **`IOptions`** instead of `IOptionsSnapshot`, no more computing and processing will be done and no delay will be created for each request.

You have to manually update the config if needed.

for more info use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-ioptionssnapshot-to-read-updated-data)